# Why can't I simply assign values to string as I can for integer?

Tags: c

`int x;x=1;` **works the same as** `int x=1;`

but

```
 char str[20];
 str="my name is bla bla";
```

**does NOT work, whereas** `char str[20]="my name is bla bla";` **works**

Working on Code block with TDM-GCC-64 compiler

Comment: got my answer, thank you.

Comment: When programming in C, you need a thorough understanding of the pointer concept. And your `str` symbol can be seen as a char pointer constant, the literal string is a constant char pointer, so the assignment is type-correct, but you're trying to assign something to a constant, which is of course impossible.

Answer (score 4):

In C language strings are just arrays of characters. One can say that the core language itself is not even aware of the existence of strings - it is a library-level concept. (With the exception of string literals, perhaps, which are core language feature and which are strings.). In all respects strings are just arrays.

In C language naked arrays are generally not copyable, neither in assignment contexts nor in initialization contexts. Instead, arrays in C instantly decay to pointers with the exception of a few special contexts:

1. Unary `&` operator
2. `sizeof` operator
3. `_Alignof` operator
4. Initialization of a `char[]` array with a string literal (in which case array copying actually takes place)

Your example with *initialization* belongs to the above list, which is why it works. But your example with *assignment* is not an exception. In the latter case the general rule for array is applied: you can't assign arrays in C. In you want to copy a naked array, you have to use user-level or library-level code.

Comment: The important thing that's missing from this answer is that C doesn't really have strings.  It has arrays of `char`.  That's why all the limitations that apply to arrays also apply to strings.

Comment: @NathanFellman Or that C really does have _strings_ - in its standard library, just not as defined by other languages.